# put facebook wall in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-widget, response

I'm trying to integrate posting to one's wall from within my app.i try this code but i get response like this

```
   public void postMessageOnWall(String msg) {
        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
         try {
                String response = mFacebook.request("feed");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", "dfsagfsadfsafsadf by thamil");
                parameters.putString("description", "test test test");

                response = mFacebook.request("feed", parameters);
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                        response.equals("false")) {
                   Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                }
         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

            }




' {"error":{"message":"No node specified","type":"Exception"}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use FacebookRocket API http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket#idc-cover

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the feed you wish to post to, e.g.

```
response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

This will post to your own feed.

There are some useful examples provided by Facebook on GitHub, such as [this one](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/tests/src/com/facebook/android/tests/Tests.java) (scroll down to the **testAuthenticatedApi()** method for an example of what you're trying to do).